# Typo3: powermailer: one form on different places on the same page

Tags: forms, typo3

I have a page where I need one form in the main content and one in the footer.
The problem is that these two forms should be connected.

The form in the main content have three input fields for name, email etc. and the one in the footer has two radio buttons.
The radiobuttons work as "I agree" so they have to, somehow, be connected to the other fields.

I use typo3 with powermailer.

I have a thougth of using css and just move those radiobuttons to the footer.
But I would like a more permanent sollution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is currently no better solution, but youre on the right way with CSS.

If i understood you correctly. You are trying to implement two plugins which are connected to each other. This is impossible with powermail.

Dirty, but useable is the CSS way or maybe a JavaScript solution for some fancy effects.